# Python print statement on new line

Tags: python, string

I have a program that prints out strings from an array like this:

```
for x in strings
    print x,
```

Which works fine, the strings all print on the same line which is what I want, but then I also have to print out a string that isn't part of the array on a new line. Like this:

```
for x in strings:
    print x,
print second_name
```

Which ends up all printing on the same line. I want second_name to print on a newline though, how do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the newline character `\n`:

```
print '\n' + second_name
```

Comment: Thank you, never knew this was a thing in Python. Coming from Java, this is very nice to see!

Answer (score 4):

I personally think it would be best to use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) here:

```
print " ".join(strings)
print second_name
```

The for-loop just seems like overkill.

Comment: Sorry, I just started learning Python. 'str.join' will print out all the objects in an array?

Comment: @opiop65 - It will print out a string with the items in `strings` joined by spaces.  Using `str.join` as I showed above will yeild the same results as the for-loop.  The only difference is that it is a cleaner and somewhat faster.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution is that if you used "print" without final newline in a cycle, add it after this cycle; so the code will look like

```
for x in strings:
    print x,
print ## this terminates the first output line
print second_name
```

This is kind of the most proper usage of print "API" according to its concepts.

OTOH the answer by K DawG does essentialy the same in other way, putting the default ending '\n' at beginning of the next "print", and, stream nature of stdout makes results of these two variants identical.

NB your construct isn't portable directly to Python3. Python2's print adds a space before each argument unless output isn't at beginning of line. Python3's separator is applied between arguments, but not before the first one in a line. So this manner (cloned from BASIC) isn't perspective and should be replaced with an own manner, like:

```
out = ''
for x in strings:
out += ' ' + x
print(out[1:])
print(second_name)
```

but, `" ".join(strings)` is generally faster and more clear to read.

Comment: Well I'm not worried about porting any code to Python 3, I'm writing this for personal reasons and have no need to port anything. But thank you for the information.